# Proof by Induction for Factorial with Sum

Tags: solution-verification, induction

So, the problem is about solving the following statement through induction:

$$\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{n} + i^2(i-1)!\right) = n!, n \in\mathbb{N}^+$$

What I've done so far:

Beginning (for $n=1$):
$$\frac{1}{2}(1+1)=1=1!$$ (shortened it for the question)

Induction Step:

Show $\frac{1}{n+2} * \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(\frac{1}{n+1}+i^2(i-1)!) = (n+1)!$

What I got so far:

$$ \begin{aligned} \frac{1}{n+2}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+i^2(i-1)!\right) &= \frac{1}{n+2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}+i^2(i-1)!\right)+1\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+i^2(i-1)!\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{n+1}{n+2}\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}+i^2(i-1)!\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{n+1}{n+2} n! \\
&= \end{aligned}$$

but from here I am kind of stumped. I tried two things:

1. $= \frac{1+n!n+n!}{n+2}$
2. $= \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{n!(n+1)}{n+2} = \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{(n+1)!}{n+2}$

But I don't see how I'd get to $(n+1)!$ from here. Hope I used the correct tags. Thanks anyone for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second step is wrong:
$$\frac{1}{n+2}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+i^2*((i-1)!)\right) \neq \frac{1}{n+2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}+i^2*((i-1)!))+1\right)$$. Instead:
$$\frac{1}{n+2}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+i^2((i-1)!)\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{n+2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+i^2((i-1)!)\right)+\frac1{n+1}+(n+1)(n+1)!\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{n+2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac1{n(n+1)}+i^2((i-1)!)\right)+\frac1{n+1}+(n+1)(n+1)!\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{n+2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}+i^2((i-1)!)\right) -\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac1{n+1}+(n+1)(n+1)!\right)$$
using induction hypothesis, this is
$$=\frac{1}{n+2}\left((n+1)!+(n+1)(n+1)!\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{n+2}\left((n+2)!\right)$$
$$=(n+1)!$$
However, I would strongly recommend doing this without induction:
$$\begin{aligned} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{n} + i^2(i-1)!\right) &= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( i(i)!\right)+\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
\\&= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \left( (i+1)!-i!\right)\right)+1
\\&=((n+1)!-1)+1 \end{aligned}$$
where one observes that $(i+1)!-i!$ telescopes. Now, divide by $(n+1)$ to complete the proof.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I finally managed to solve it. Some steps were a bit difficult to follow, but I understood in the end. The eye-opener for me was when I realized the sum in the hypothesis (without the 1/(n+1) ) is basically (n+1)!, which I totally oversaw. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The first equality is false, it should be
$$ =\frac{1}{n+2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+i^2(i-1)!\right)+\frac{1}{n+1}+(n+1)^2n!\right). $$
I think it would be easier if you rephrase the equality you want to prove as
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n i\times i!=(n+1)!-1. $$
You already proved the case $n=1$, the induction step is now easier.

> $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i\times i!=(n+1)(n+1)!+(n+1)!-1=(n+2)(n+1)!-1=(n+2)!-1 $$
>  or, without induction,
>  $$ \sum_{i=1}^n i\times i!=\sum_{i=1}^n ((i+1)!-i!)=(n+1)!-1. $$

Comment: Thanks for the help! I don't quite understand how you rephrased it to sum i×i! = (n+1)! - 1. What does the × mean in this context?

Comment: The initial sum can be written as $$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{n}+i*i!\right)=(n+1)n!=(n+1)!$$ and the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n}$ equals $1$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.